# Java regex for Uk phone numbers and phone codes

Tags: java, regex

I looked a bit around the older posts but couldn't reeally find an answer for my case.

I have a regex

```
"(?:(?:(?:\+|00)44[\s\-\.]?)?(?:(?:\(?0\)?)[\s\-\.]?)?(?:\d[\s\-\.]?){10})"
```

that matches the pattern below

```
+44 1642 468 592
+44-(0)207-54-60-022
(0)201 234 5678
0207 1345 678
01642.85.08.50
```

but not

```
(017683) 927 43

(0207) 1345-678

(0207) 1345 678
```

I did found a regex who works for the pattern (017683) 927 43 but I was wondering if this regex could be simplify to match phone numbers with 4, 5 or 6 digits between parenthesis ?

For pattern : `(017683) 927 43`

```
^\(0[0-9]{5}\) [0-9]{5}$|^\(01[0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{6}$|^\(01[0-9]1\)? [0-9]{3}? [0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: If you have the possibility to use an external library, consider using Google's libphonenumber

Answer (score 4):

I would say , that You should not rely  on the  regex patterns  in this  case.

Basically , you should know number standard you are about to accept  and this  will tell you how much 0-9 digits you expect to consume from user input. Everything that is over or under is discarded and user is informed  with "Please enter valid number".

To get amount of digits, you need to take user input and remove all non digit characters from it. This will standardize anything user enters :

```
+44123 456 789
+44-123-456-789
4412345 6789
44 123-456-789
```

etc..

and even

```
+44 123-----456----789
```

to the same string  44123456789

After this done , if length of the string is matching with international standard  ,  we can start to break it by positions to country code, city  and analyze is there  valid  country , city , etc...

When you use regexp, you actually describing  what symbols you agree to meet on positions from 0 to X. So if you expect to have "+,-,Nothing,[0-9]" as first element, you need to explicitly mention this in regexp expresion **(\+\-[0-9]){0,1}** .

And this is only for the  first position!

If you expect 15 of those, this will make regexp completely unreadable  not only by other people , but for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?:(?:(?:\+|00)44[\s\-\.]?)?(?:(?:\(?0\)?)[\s\-\.]?)?(?:\d[\s\-\.]?){10})|(?=\(?\d*\)?[\x20\-\d]*)(\(?\)?\x20*\-*\d){11}
```

[Demo here](http://regexr.com/3bf73)